# How do I make a chrome app write to a file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I just started learning about chrome applications and I'm fairly new to the javascript aspect of it while I do have some experience with the HTML side of it. How do I create an application that has a check box (The check box will be html) and then have a button (which all also be in html) and this button will write to a file on my desktop whether the check box is checked or unchecked? i.e. it will write either true or false?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You are not asking a question which can be answered easily because "How do I create an application...?" questions imply that you want someone to write your code for you. Please write some code, and if it doesn't work then come back and post another question.

Comment: I sort of do want some kind of generalized code since I'm really clueless on how a chrome apps really are. But since my question is kind of broad ill just ask for starters, how do I get a button that i create in the html to do a simple action such as open a web page maybe because inline code such as "<href>" is not allowed? And i dont know how that would work with javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Saving to a file is not as as easy as it sounds. I suggest checking the Chrome App examples ([found here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159062)), loading the extensions and seeing which one does what you want. THEN you go and check the code. The example that would work best for you would be the **mini-code-edit** one, which has both loading a file and saving to a file.

Still, if you won't do that, this example code should work:

```
//Selector for your "Save" button
document.querySelector("#saveButton").onclick = saveToFile;
//Save variables
var fileEntry;
var hasWriteAccess;
//Save methods
function saveToFile()
{
    if (fileEntry && hasWriteAccess) {
    writeEditorToFile(fileEntry);
    } else {
        chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({ type: 'saveFile', suggestedName: "suggestedFileName.txt"}, onChosenFileToSave);
    }
}

function setFile(theFileEntry, isWritable) {
  fileEntry = theFileEntry;
  hasWriteAccess = isWritable;
}

function writeEditorToFile(theFileEntry) {
  theFileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
    fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log("Write failed: " + e.toString());
    };

    var blob = new Blob(["You put whatever you want written to your file here."]);
    fileWriter.truncate(blob.size);
    fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
        //handleDocumentChange(theFileEntry.fullPath);
        console.log("Write completed.");
      };

      fileWriter.write(blob);
    }
  }, errorHandler);
}

var onChosenFileToSave = function(theFileEntry) {
  setFile(theFileEntry, true);
  writeEditorToFile(theFileEntry);
};
```

This was taken from the example I mentioned. Also, remember to add **"fileSystem": ["write"]** to your manifest.